# Как установить nls переменные в Adonis.js

Tags: oracle, backend, adonis.js

Пытаюсь использовать Adonis в качестве бэкэнда. Возникла потребность изменить значение NLS_DATE_FORMAT.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY.MM.DD'
```

Не подскажете в каком месте вставить исполнение этой эскуэлки, что бы исполнялась при установлении соединения?

Answer (score 0):

В англоязычной ветке подсказали достаточно очевидный совет (сам так не пробовал, потому что в документации адониса про это не говорилось) - указать в файле .env. Попробовал - работает.